# How can we start mongo as process using ProcessBuilder (java) with authentication

Tags: java, mongodb

How can we start mongo as process using ProcessBuilder (java) with authentication.

My mongo server is up with authentication.
Earlier code was.

```
   String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
   String executableName = (osName != null && osName.contains("indows")) ? "mongo.exe" : "mongo";
   String[] commandLine = new String[]{
       PathUtil.findExecutable(executableName),
            "localhost" + ":" + "27017" + "/" + "test", getScriptPath(path)
   };

   ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commandLine);
   processBuilder.directory(new File(getScriptPath(path)).getParentFile());
   processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

   Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

How can I add username/password in authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Add user/password to mongodb url like this

```
String[] commandLine = new String[]{
    PathUtil.findExecutable(executableName), "user:password@localhost:27017/test", getScriptPath(path)
};
```